# serverless python error: No such file or directory: '/tmp/_temp-sls-py-req' -> '/tmp/sls-py-req'

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I am working on a project using serverless framework and python. I've used `serverless-python-requirements` plugins and it still giving me an error.

The deployment is fine, but every time I trigger the function it gives me this error:

```
[ERROR] FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/_temp-sls-py-req' -> '/tmp/sls-py-req'
```

Here's a piece of my `serverless.yml` file:

```
custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: true
    zip: true

plugins:
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-python-requirements
```

and here's a piece of my code that causing the error:

```
try:
    import unzip_requirements
except ImportError:
    pass

import json
import boto3
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
from boto3.dynamodb.types import TypeDeserializer
```

All I knew was, it was giving an error when importing `unzip_requirements` (line 2). I followed the documentation and it requires me to do the import.

The cause of the error seems like because it can't find something on lambda `/tmp` folder.

Answer (score 1):

We ran into a similar issue with serverless-python-requirements recently. For us it was caused by a deployment, where serverless didn't recognize the requirements correctly for one function and tried to unzip an empty .requirements.zip file as a result. The failing line [unzip_requirements.py#L22](https://github.com/serverless/serverless-python-requirements/blob/1f8039fe6504de97b20d8b3036f7e795955b10c1/unzip_requirements.py#L22):

```
#...
zipfile.ZipFile(zip_requirements, 'r').extractall(tempdir)

# the following line fails as the extract command unzips nothing
# and doesn't create any directory that could be renamed

os.rename(tempdir, pkgdir) #  Atomic
```

Therefore I'd recommend trying out the following:
Use pandas as a layer instead, e.g. by using a [public pandas layer](https://github.com/keithrozario/Klayers/blob/master/pipeline/config/Klayers-prodp38/packages.csv#L53) or creating you own one following the [plugin instructions](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-python-requirements) for layers e.g.

```
# in serverless.yaml        
custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    layer: true
#...
functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    layers:
      - Ref: PythonRequirementsLambdaLayer
```

or if the requirements are small enough, then try the unzipped version. This solved it for us with serverless version 2.69.0

I also heard that potentially downgrading to serverless 1.83 addressed a similar issue in the past, but couldn't verify that so far. Good luck